# Export from Illustrator to Photoshop at a specific resolution

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

I got application design as .ai file, Adobe Illustrator. The design is for mobile application and I have a nice plug-in in Photoshop and Gimp that can easily export layers (and name them) to fit all mobile screens.

I read on multiple places that I have to export .ai file to .psd file. Now, the plug-in does not like up-scaling (neither do I) so I have to export AI file to PSD at a specific resolution. Let's say at 1080x1920 pixels.

How do I do that? Do I first have to resize all AI images to this resolution and then export, or this can be done automatically?

In the end, can I keep layers in PDF unrasterized or all buttons will be glued to the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not resize your artwork. On the export settings there is a option in the dialog box, just choose pixels as the units and then you can asign specific values in pixels.

Do not forget to check the box anti-alias on, and export as rgb colour mode. Play with the rest of the options, for example preserving the layers, editable texts, etc.

To keep your butons as separated layers in photoshop make them is separated layers in Ilustrator as well.

Comment: Sounds promising. I will check it and come back with marking this as a reply or asking more.